# How to get the value between 2 characters in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

Hi everyone i have like this value in my column:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?dsk-revision 1.0?><Descriptor><pde><a><dov>784512</dov></a></pde></Descriptor>
```

I would retrieve just :

```
<dov>784512</dov>
```

Do you have any ideas?

**Thank you !**

Comment: Is the data type of your column XMLTYPE?

Comment: @Boneist column type was string and value was a XML value (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?dsk-revision 1.0?>
<Descriptor>...) but it was saved as string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select x.*,
       regexp_replace(str, '<pde><a>(.*)</a></pde>', '\1')
from (select '<pde><a><dov>784512</dov></a></pde>' as str from dual) x;
```

Or `regexp_substr()`:

```
select x.*,
       regexp_substr(str, '<dov>.*</dov>')
from (select '<pde><a><dov>784512</dov></a></pde>' as str from dual) x;
```

I am unclear whether you want the string because the "dov"s or between the "pde/a"s.

Answer (score 0):

With `SUBSTR + INSTR`:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2  (select '<pde><a><dov>784512</dov></a></pde>' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, instr(col, '<dov>', 1, 1),
  4                     instr(col, '</dov>', 1, 1) + 6 - instr(col, '<dov>')) result
  5  from test;

RESULT
-----------------
<dov>784512</dov>

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use REGEXP_REPLACE with specified mask:

```
select x.*,
       regexp_replace(str, '.*<a>(.*)</a>.*', '\1'), -- anything between <a> </a>
       regexp_replace(str, '.*(<dov>.*</dov>).*', '\1'), -- anything between <dov> </dov> tag (tag included)
       regexp_replace(str, '.*<pde><a>(.*)</a></pde>.*', '\1'), -- anything between <pde><a> </a></pde>
       regexp_replace(str, '.*<pde><a>(<dov>.*</dov>)</a></pde>.*', '\1') -- anything between <pde><a> </a></pde> that is inside <dov> </dov> tag (tag included)
from (select '<pde><a><dov>784512</dov></a></pde>' as str from dual) x;
```